# Cannot convert from char* to void**

Tags: c, casting

I modified the following code

```
void aligned_free(void *p) {
    free(((void**) p)[-1]);
}
```

to

```
void aligned_free(void **p) {
    free((p)[-1]);
}
```

with function call

```
char* a = (char*)aligned_malloc(10000,64);
aligned_free(a);
```

and the compiler gives the error "cannot convert from char* to void**". Why the pointer char* cannot be converted to void**, but void* is OK?

Comment: Because `void **` is a pointer to a pointer, and `char *` (or `void *`) is just a pointer

Comment: The important distinction is that `void **` points to something different than `char *` does.  `void *` is a generic point, but `void **` is not.  `void *` can point to anything.  `void **` must point to a `void *`.

Comment: I wonder what made you want to remove the cast in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void *` is a generic pointer.  An object of type `void *` can point to anything.  A `void **`, however, can only point to an object of type `void *`.  A `char` is not a `void *`, so the conversion fails.